# Constructing real forms of the Tits-Freudenthal magic square for (Rosenfeld) projective planes

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, symmetric-spaces, exceptional-groups, octonions

If $\mathbb{K},\mathbb{L} \in \{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C},\mathbb{H},\mathbb{O}\}$ then the Rosenfeld projective ("elliptic"?) plane $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{K}\otimes\mathbb{L})$ is "the" compact Riemannian [symmetric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_space) associated with the non-compact Lie algebra $\tilde L_3(\mathbb{K},\mathbb{L})$ given by the following version of the Tits-Freudenthal *[magic square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freudenthal_magic_square)*:

$$\begin{array}{r|c|c|c|c|}
&\mathbb{R}&\mathbb{C}&\mathbb{H}&\mathbb{O}\\\hline
\mathbb{R}&\mathfrak{so}(1,2)&\mathfrak{su}(1,2)&\mathfrak{sp}(1,2)&\mathfrak{f}_4(\mathfrak{so}_9)\\\hline
\mathbb{C}&\mathfrak{su}(1,2)&\mathfrak{su}(1,2) \oplus \mathfrak{su}(1,2)&\mathfrak{su}(2,4)&\mathfrak{e}_6(\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathfrak{so}_{10})\\\hline
\mathbb{H}&\mathfrak{sp}(1,2)&\mathfrak{su}(2,4)&\mathfrak{so}(4,8)&\mathfrak{e}_7(\mathfrak{su}_{2}\oplus\mathfrak{so}_{12})\\\hline
\mathbb{O}&\mathfrak{f}_4(\mathfrak{so}_9)&\mathfrak{e}_6(\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathfrak{so}_{10})&\mathfrak{e}_7(\mathfrak{su}_{2}\oplus\mathfrak{so}_{12})&\mathfrak{e}_8(\mathfrak{so}_{16})\\\hline
\end{array}$$

(Notation is hopefully understandable: in the case of exceptional Lie algebras, the real form is indicated by putting their maximal compact subalgebra in parentheses.  For example, $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{H}\otimes\mathbb{H}) = \mathit{SO}_{12}/\mathit{S}(\mathit{O}_4\times \mathit{O}_8)$ and $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{C}\otimes\mathbb{O}) = \mathit{E}_6/(\mathit{U}_1\cdot\mathit{Spin}_{10})$.  I am [unsure about finite coverings](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/167890/real-lie-groups-versus-real-linear-algebraic-groups-differences-in-connexity-an), which is why I only put Lie algebras in this table and why I put quotation marks around "the" above; but this is irrelevant for my question.)

This table is found, e.g., in Hans Freudenthal's 1964 report "Lie Groups in the Foundations of Geometry" (*Advances in Math.* **1**, 145–190), ¶4.16 on p. 172.  It is also found in Robert Goss's 2015 Ph.D. thesis [*The topology of the higher projective planes*](http://wrap.warwick.ac.uk/77125/) in §2.3 but with an incorrect claim as to its construction.

When the set of $3\times 3$ Hermitian matrices with coordinates in $\mathbb{K}\otimes\mathbb{L}$ is a Jordan algebra, then $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{K}\otimes\mathbb{L})$ can be defined as the set of trace $1$ idempotents of that algebra.  But as far as I understand, there is no such construction of $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{K}\otimes\mathbb{L})$ from $\mathbb{K}\otimes\mathbb{L}$ in the case of $\mathbb{H}\otimes\mathbb{O}$ and $\mathbb{O}\otimes\mathbb{O}$.  (Rosenfeld's book *Geometry of Lie Groups* seems to suggest that there is one, but I find it very difficult to understand what this book actually says.)  Instead, the way we know which particular real form of the magic square to use is that it gives a symmetric space of the desired real dimension $2pq$ (with $p := \dim_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{K})$ and $q := \dim_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{L})$) and desired real rank $\min(p,q)$.

Anyway, my question is:

> How can we construct the real form $\tilde L_3(\mathbb{K},\mathbb{L})$ given in the above table from $\mathbb{K}$ and $\mathbb{L}$ using an algebraic construction?

I emphasize that the difficult part is getting the correct real form: the complexification is the usual magic square of Lie algebras.  There are a number of constructions given in Barton & Sudbery's article ["Magic squares and matrix models of Lie algebras"](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0203010), but unless I missed something, they *do not* produce the above tables (for $\mathbb{K},\mathbb{L} \in \{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C},\mathbb{H},\mathbb{O}\}$, their $L_3(\mathbb{K},\mathbb{L})$ defined in theorem 4.4 gives a compact real form; and if we replace $\mathbb{K}$ and $\mathbb{L}$ by the split form of the algebra, the result, shown near the end of section 7 of their paper, produces a different table from the one above).

So, is there a way to produce the above table without resorting to filtering real forms by their real rank?

Answer (score 3):

Alberto Elduque obtained all real forms of exceptional Lie algebras in his variant of Freudenthal square in [A new look at Freudenthal's magic square](http://www.crcnetbase.com/doi/abs/10.1201/9781420003451.ch12),  Non-associative algebra and its applications, 149–165,
Lect. Notes Pure Appl. Math., 246.

There is also a [PhD thesis](http://www.ims.cuhk.edu.hk/~leung/PhD%20students/Thesis%20Yong%20Dong%20Huang.pdf) (pdf link) of Yongdong Huang that shows how to get all Riemannian symmetric spaces out of a magic square construction.

Comment: Obtaining every real form is not what I'm after: the point is to obtain precisely the "right" ones in a uniform way from $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{H}$, $\mathbb{O}$.  **But** the paper by Elduque you mention references a remark in another paper by the same author ("[The Magic Square and Symmetric Compositions](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rmi/1087482023)", spec. rk. 3.2) which appears to describe the same construction as in the answer by Marek Mitros and give the right real forms, at least for the exceptional algebras, (contd.)

Comment: (contd.) namely the forms of $F_4$, $E_6$, $E_7$ and $E_8$ with respective Cartan index $-20$, $-14$, $-5$ and $8$, merely by changing two signs in the Barton-Sudbery construction.  So this would indeed be the construction I was hoping for (assuming it also works in the non-exceptional cases; I'll try to check that).

Comment: PS: On the other hand, Huang's thesis doesn't seem too relevant here.  It's not really an algebraic construction, and I seem to understand that the octonionic grassmanians are defined in an ad hoc fashion.  (I find the details fairly sketchy; there is a more readable paper by Huang and Leung in *Math. Ann.* in 2011, but even there I'm not completely sure what it is they actually construct.)

Comment: Thanks for the update. What I meant was that if Elduque claims to obtain _all_ real forms then what remains is to check whether he obtained the crucial ones in "one table".

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using Barton-Sudbery method for $\mathbb K \otimes \mathbb L$ with one adjustment. In space $Tri (\mathbb K) +Tri (\mathbb L)+\mathbb K\otimes \mathbb L +\mathbb K\otimes \mathbb L+\mathbb K\otimes \mathbb L$ change sign in result of bracket of two spaces $\mathbb K \otimes \mathbb L$. I tried this method in 2008 when I created GAP script for generation of all algebras in magic square. However I did not finish my work, so I do not give 100% guarantee.

Here is example with description whan sign should be changed. I show the difference on $so(8,1)$ and $so_9$ Lie algebras example. Let $e_{i,j}$ be matrix having $-1$ on $i,j$ coordinate and $1$ on $j,i$ and zeros otherwise. Let $f_{i,j}$ be matrix having $1$ on $i,j$ and $j,i$ coordinates and zeros otherwise. Let $V_8$ be space generated by $e_{i,9}$ or $f_{i,9}$ for $i=1..8$. One can easily verify following results.

1. $[e_{i,j}, e_{k,j}]=e_{i,k}$
2. $[f_{i,j}, f_{k,j}]=-e_{i,k}$
3. $e_{i,j}$ for $1 \leqslant i < j \leqslant 9$ generate $so_9$
4. $e_{i,j}$ for $1 \leqslant i < j \leqslant 8$ and $f_{i,9}$, $i=1..8$ generate $so_{8,1}$

As one can see the $so_{8,1}$ can be obtained from $so_9$ by changing sign on results of $[V_8,V_8]$ brackets.

The same method can be applied to Barton-Sudbery Lie algebras by changing sign on $[A,A]$, $[B,B]$ brackets where $A, B, C$ are three components of $\mathbb K \otimes \mathbb L$.

In my opinion there is no good definition of exceptional Lie groups. One would expect Lie group as being symmetry group of something. For example $F_4$ is defined as isometry group of $\mathbb O P^2$ projective plane over octonions. How to define $\mathbb O P^2$ ? We can use Jordan algebra do define it in algebraic way. How to define it in geometric way ?
Next question is how to define "bioctonionic projective plane" $\mathbb C \otimes \mathbb OP^2$ ? Baez in his "[The Octonions](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/octonions/octonions.html)" defined it as quotient of $E_6$ by the subgroup. Lie group $E_6$ is defined from it's Lie algebra. Lie algebra $e_6$ is defined in abstract way as bracket on some 78-dimensional vector space.

Similar for $E_7$ and $E_8$ there is missing nice definition we expect. Rosenfeld seemed to had some ideas but as you say - it is difficult to read and understand. Freudenthal worked on "octonionic projective geometry" but for me is also difficult to read and understand.

*All things are difficult before they are easy* (Thomas Fuller). Exceptional Lie groups looks difficult, so it means they are not well understood yet.

Comment: I had considered this modification and I thought it was too simple to work; but it seems you're right: see my comments on the answer by Vít Tuček: apparently Alberto Elduque considered the variation on the Barton-Sudbery construction that you mention, and it seems that it might indeed give the "right" real forms in every case.