# Reference for bi-octonionic projective plane $\left(\mathbb{C}\otimes\mathbb{O}\right)P^{2}$

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, projective-geometry, octonions

I'm not well versed in projective geometry since it is not really my field. I read in [1] about the existance of a projective plane $\left(\mathbb{C}\otimes\mathbb{O}\right)P^{2}$ defined on bi-quaternions. I think it might be defined through the use of the Jordan algebra $\mathfrak{h}_{3}\left(\mathbb{C}\otimes\mathbb{O}\right)$ but I'm wondering if there's some reference for a direct construction of such "projective plane" or if its existance is merely speculative.

[1] Baez, J. C. .2002. The octonions. Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 39.

Comment: It is the compact Riemannian symmetric space associated with the real form of $E_6$ whose maximal compact subgroup is (some finite quotient of?) $U_1 × \mathit{Spin}_{10}$, see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253227/constructing-real-forms-of-the-tits-freudenthal-magic-square-for-rosenfeld-pro). I'm not sure there is a known construction from the algebra $\mathbb{C} \otimes \mathbb{C}$, however.

Comment: (In the tables of [this Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_space), it is known as “EIII”.)

Comment: It's also known as the "first Rosenfeld plane", see https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.05451 for information about its homotopy type and some references.